# Using Chai with Angular CLI app

Tags: angular, chai, immutable.js, chai-immutable

I want to use chai-immutable library with an Angular app that is generated using the Angular app. I will use chai-immutable and mocha to write unit tests for my reducer for the ngrx/store.

How do I go about configuring the webpack file to allow me to run Chai and Mocha, because the standard framework seems to be Jasmine for Angular.